# How to put an image on top of a button in tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter, drag-and-drop

I am making a physics simulator using tkinter and I want to have an image on top of a button in dnd, tkinter so that when I move the button, the image moves. How do I do this? The image and code are in the same folder.

I have tried adding an image by using it like a normal button but it gives an error. The code is the code from help(dnd) in python. I am using python 3.6. I need to identify the type of component the button is when I move it

Also, if anyone can tell me how to use collision detect to detect when 2 images are touching.

```
import tkinter

__all__ = ["dnd_start", "DndHandler"]

def dnd_start(source, event):
    h = DndHandler(source, event)
    if h.root:
        return h
    else:
        return None


# The class that does the work

class DndHandler:

    root = None

    def __init__(self, source, event):
        if event.num > 5:
            return
        root = event.widget._root()
        try:
            root.__dnd
            return # Don't start recursive dnd
        except AttributeError:
            root.__dnd = self
            self.root = root
        self.source = source
        self.target = None
        self.initial_button = button = event.num
        self.initial_widget = widget = event.widget
        self.release_pattern = "<B%d-ButtonRelease-%d>" % (button, button)
        self.save_cursor = widget['cursor'] or ""
        widget.bind(self.release_pattern, self.on_release)
        widget.bind("<Motion>", self.on_motion)
        widget['cursor'] = "hand2"

    def __del__(self):
        root = self.root
        self.root = None
        if root:
            try:
                del root.__dnd
            except AttributeError:
                pass

    def on_motion(self, event):
        x, y = event.x_root, event.y_root
        target_widget = self.initial_widget.winfo_containing(x, y)
        source = self.source
        new_target = None
        while target_widget:
            try:
                attr = target_widget.dnd_accept
            except AttributeError:
                pass
            else:
                new_target = attr(source, event)
                if new_target:
                    break
            target_widget = target_widget.master
        old_target = self.target
        if old_target is new_target:
            if old_target:
                old_target.dnd_motion(source, event)
        else:
            if old_target:
                self.target = None
                old_target.dnd_leave(source, event)
            if new_target:
                new_target.dnd_enter(source, event)
                self.target = new_target

    def on_release(self, event):
        self.finish(event, 1)

    def cancel(self, event=None):
        self.finish(event, 0)

    def finish(self, event, commit=0):
        target = self.target
        source = self.source
        widget = self.initial_widget
        root = self.root
        try:
            del root.__dnd
            self.initial_widget.unbind(self.release_pattern)
            self.initial_widget.unbind("<Motion>")
            widget['cursor'] = self.save_cursor
            self.target = self.source = self.initial_widget = self.root = None
            if target:
                if commit:
                    target.dnd_commit(source, event)
                else:
                    target.dnd_leave(source, event)
        finally:
            source.dnd_end(target, event)

class Icon:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.canvas = self.label = self.id = None

    def attach(self, canvas, x=10, y=10):
        if canvas is self.canvas:
            self.canvas.coords(self.id, x, y)
            return
        if self.canvas:
            self.detach()
        if not canvas:
            return
        label = tkinter.Label(canvas, text=self.name,
                              borderwidth=2, relief="raised")
        id = canvas.create_window(x, y, window=label, anchor="nw")
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.label = label
        self.id = id
        label.bind("<ButtonPress>", self.press)

    def detach(self):
        canvas = self.canvas
        if not canvas:
            return
        id = self.id
        label = self.label
        self.canvas = self.label = self.id = None
        canvas.delete(id)
        label.destroy()

    def press(self, event):
        if dnd_start(self, event):
            # where the pointer is relative to the label widget:
            self.x_off = event.x
            self.y_off = event.y
            # where the widget is relative to the canvas:
            self.x_orig, self.y_orig = self.canvas.coords(self.id)

    def move(self, event):
        x, y = self.where(self.canvas, event)
        self.canvas.coords(self.id, x, y)

    def putback(self):
        self.canvas.coords(self.id, self.x_orig, self.y_orig)

    def where(self, canvas, event):
        # where the corner of the canvas is relative to the screen:
        x_org = canvas.winfo_rootx()
        y_org = canvas.winfo_rooty()
        # where the pointer is relative to the canvas widget:
        x = event.x_root - x_org
        y = event.y_root - y_org
        # compensate for initial pointer offset
        return x - self.x_off, y - self.y_off

    def dnd_end(self, target, event):
        pass


class Tester:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.top = tkinter.Toplevel(root)
        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self.top, width=100, height=100)
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
        self.canvas.dnd_accept = self.dnd_accept

    def dnd_accept(self, source, event):
        return self

    def dnd_enter(self, source, event):
        self.canvas.focus_set() # Show highlight border
        x, y = source.where(self.canvas, event)
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = source.canvas.bbox(source.id)
        dx, dy = x2-x1, y2-y1
        self.dndid = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+dx, y+dy)
        self.dnd_motion(source, event)

    def dnd_motion(self, source, event):
        x, y = source.where(self.canvas, event)
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.canvas.bbox(self.dndid)
        self.canvas.move(self.dndid, x-x1, y-y1)

    def dnd_leave(self, source, event):
        self.top.focus_set() # Hide highlight border
        self.canvas.delete(self.dndid)
        self.dndid = None

    def dnd_commit(self, source, event):
        self.dnd_leave(source, event)
        x, y = source.where(self.canvas, event)
        source.attach(self.canvas, x, y)


def test():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.geometry("+1+1")
    tkinter.Button(command=root.quit, text="Quit").pack()
    t1 = Tester(root)
    t1.top.geometry("+1+60")
    t2 = Tester(root)
    t2.top.geometry("+120+60")
    t3 = Tester(root)
    t3.top.geometry("+240+60")
    i1 = Icon("ICON1")
    i2 = Icon("ICON2")
    i3 = Icon("ICON3")
    i1.attach(t1.canvas)
    i2.attach(t2.canvas)
    i3.attach(t3.canvas)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: _"I have tried adding an image by using it like a normal button but it gives an error"_ - what's the error?

Comment: You're designing a GUI with movable `Button`s? Sounds interesting…or you're using the wrong type of widget entirely.

Comment: The error is:widget.bind(self.release_pattern, self.on_release, img= "sdgsg.png")
TypeError: bind() got an unexpected keyword argument 'img'